# CSS Firefox - Top Padding Changes Width

Tags: html, css, firefox, modal-dialog

I have a responsive web page in which I am trying to show a modal with an image inside. The following is the html of the modal

```
<div id="open_modal" class="modal">
    <div id="chicken">
        <img src="images/chicken.png" alt="McChicken"/>
        <div class="kosullar" title="lorem ipsum">Katılım Koşulları</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following is the css I have for the modal

```
.modal {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1001;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 77px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

#chicken{
    height: 100%;   
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
}

#chicken img{
    height: 100%;   
    float: left;
}

.kosullar{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #2B9BC8 !important;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100%;
}
```

As you can see in the css I have added 77px top padding to the modal class, so that it wouldn't overlap with my navigation bar. Other than that the modal should have the same height as the display and its width should be automatically calculated according to the aspect ratio of the image. This works very well on Chrome (and IE as well surprisingly), but it misbehaves on Firefox. On Firefox the image looks as it's supposed to, but the width of the modal is wider than it should be. To be specific, the width of the modal is what it should have been if there was no padding on the modal. How should I modify this css so that Firefox will calculate the width of the modal successfully. You can visit adwin.com.tr to see the problem for yourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
#chicken img {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all mention `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` (in case of HTML5) if you have not mentioned and then try adding

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
```

in you modal class, this should help you solve the width issue.

Alternatively you can override the bootstrap's

```
*, *:before, *:after {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

to

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
    }
```

You can also refer [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)

Comment: Here is a great article about border-box - http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/